How to solve the dependency of Python 3.12 on Ubuntu 24.04LTS
Recently, my Xubuntu 22.04LTS told me that it is upgradable to 24.04LTS, and I did.
However the terminal says that there is unsolvable dependency, which libpython3.12t64 has, on libpython3.12-stdlib (= 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1).
In addition to that, it says libpython3.12-stdlib 3.12.5-1+jammy1, which is a broken package, is tried being installed.
Consequently, I cannot install gdb, hexchat-python3, initramfs-tools-bin, initramfs-tools-core, initramfs-tools, libcryptsetup12, and libpeas-1.0-0, which are on hold, as if they were sort of constipation.
Does anyone know how to solve this?
I leave the information the terminal shows, but it is written in Japanese. Sorry.
インストールすることができないパッケージがありました。おそらく、あり得
ない状況を要求したか、(不安定版ディストリビューションを使用しているの
であれば) 必要なパッケージがまだ作成されていなかったり Incoming から移
動されていないことが考えられます。
以下の情報がこの問題を解決するために役立つかもしれません:

以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
 libpython3.12t64 : 依存: libpython3.12-stdlib (= 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1) しかし、 
3.12.5-1+jammy1 はインストールされようとしています
E: 問題を解決することができません。壊れた変更禁止パッケージがあります。

Thanks, regards.

No point to adding screens of a non English result. This is an English only site.

Some packages could not be installed. Perhaps you have requested an impossible
requested or (if you are using an unstable distribution) the required package has not been created yet or has been moved from Incoming.
The required package has not yet been created or moved from Incoming (if you are using an unstable distribution).
The following information may help to resolve this issue.
The following information may help to solve this problem: - The package is not available.

The following packages have dependencies that cannot be met: libpython3.12.12
libpython3.12t64 : Dependency: libpython3.12-stdlib (= 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1) However,
3.12.5-1+jammy1 is trying to be installed
E: Unable to resolve the issue. There is a broken change-prohibited package.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

I see the exact same problem when upgrading my KDE Neon today. Python 3.12 is the system python of ubuntu 24.04 so it really needs to work.
